# How to remove Post Date from wordpress template

Tags: css, wordpress

i'm have problem with CSS coding in wordpress template , i need to remove Post Date from website
i already remove it from single-page my issue in homepage

i took this code from using "source page"

```
<div class="post-time-container">
<span class="post-time-icon fa fa-clock-o"></span>
<time class="post-time-icon fa fa-clock-o"></span>
<time class=>05.05.2015</time>
```

there is window in my template allow me to put CSS codes 
i tried

```
.time class
{
display: none;
}

.entry-date
{
display: none;




.time 
 {
 display: none;
 }
```

didn't works

please what the code i should write in this case IN CSS template window

thanks

Comment: See my updated answer below, there is updated CSS based on your code below.

Comment: kindly check the website www.producers.qa in main page there is About us and What we do above these two words there is Date i want to remove it ... i removed category using : .post-category { display: none; }

Comment: thanks for your feed guys but problem didn't solved yet ... i don't know how to edit HTML in Wordpress .. i tried to modify it .. but only thing i see in Style.css and index.css at Apperance => editor is : this template designed by ********** go to template => changelog => css editor CSS editor is empty it's space to write my code .. i don't know about code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fully agree with Paul's answer from a CSS perspective - purely as an alternative you can achieve a similar outcome by placing the following code after the opening `<?php` line of your theme's functions.php file

```
function jl_remove_post_dates() {
add_filter('the_date', '__return_false');
add_filter('the_time', '__return_false');
add_filter('the_modified_date', '__return_false');
} add_action('loop_start', 'jl_remove_post_dates');
```

With your updated question - change

```
.time 
 {
 display: none;
 }
```

to

```
time 
 {
 display: none;
 }
```

on the 'empty' css file on your editor (I am assuming this is put in place for custom css on your theme)

Comment: here's the website   

www.producers.qa

i want to remove date in  Main page 
Above About us and What we do

Comment: answer updated - but on that link I can only see a landing page, no 'about us' or 'what we do' options?

Comment: I can see it in the source but not in my browser for some reason. Did you try the css code above?

Comment: note the lack of '.' before time on my answer. Your element name is 'time' without a class so to target it in css you just write 'time {your styles here}' - if it were <time class="time"> then the element class would be 'time' and you would target this by writing .time {your styles here} in your css file

Comment: thank you very much .. it's works .. i remove the dot

Comment: Nice! Hope you understand the difference now :-) Happy learning - I would appreciate if you could mark this as the accepted answer if you're happy

Answer (score 3):

In your html file do this:

```
<time class="time">05.05.2015</time>
```

Then in your CSS file, do this:

```
.time 
{
display: none;
}
```

This will resolve your issue because you didn't have anything assigned to your div class in your html file.

Answer (score 1):

`.time class` means `<element class="time"><class>...</class></element>`. It's not what you want.

Use

```
time {...}
```

Or

```
time.classname {...} /* for HTML <time class="classname"> */
```

**EDIT:**
You wrote you have this HTML

```
<div class="post-time-container">
    <span class="post-time-icon fa fa-clock-o"></span>
    <time class=>05.05.2015</time>
```

First, remove the `=` from the 4th line. And then hide the second `time` using

```
.post-time-container time {display: none}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.entry-meta{
display:none;
}
```

This will help you.